# Unparseable date with SimpleDateFormatter

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I have a date that keeps giving me an error of

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: " 5 April 2017  "
```

All other dates (without word months) work fine

The code I am using is below:

```
VisitDate=VisitDate.trim();
if (VisitDate.matches(".*[a-z].*")){
    SimpleDateFormat changeDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_yy", Locale.UK);
    //Convert the string to a date
    Date date = changeDate.parse(VisitDate);
    //Reformat the date the way I like it
    SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy");

    //Convert back into a string
    try {
        VisitDate=dt1.format(date);
        if(VisitDate==null){
            SimpleDateFormat dt2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yy");
            //Convert back into a string
            VisitDate=dt2.format(date);
            if(VisitDate==null){
                SimpleDateFormat dt3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yy");
                //Convert back into a string
                VisitDate=dt3.format(date);
                if(VisitDate==null){
                    SimpleDateFormat dt4 = new SimpleDateFormat("d_MMM_yy");
                    //Convert back into a string
                    VisitDate=dt4.format(date);
                    if(VisitDate==null){
                        SimpleDateFormat dt5 = new SimpleDateFormat("d_MMMM_yy");
                        //Convert back into a string
                        VisitDate=dt5.format(date);
                        if(VisitDate==null){
                            SimpleDateFormat dt6 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_yy");
                            //Convert back into a string
                            VisitDate=dt6.format(date);
                            if(VisitDate==null){
                                SimpleDateFormat dt7 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_yyyy");
                                //Convert back into a string
                                VisitDate=dt7.format(date);
                                if(VisitDate==null){
                                    SimpleDateFormat dt8 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMMM_yyyy");
                                    //Convert back into a string
                                    VisitDate=dt8.format(date);
                                    if(VisitDate==null){
                                        VisitDate=VisitDate.replaceAll("\\s", "");

                                        SimpleDateFormat dt9 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
                                        //Convert back into a string
                                        VisitDate=dt9.format(date);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error(e+"->No visit Date frmo here with the original date as: "+date);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: And for goodness sake, put all those `SimpleDateFormat` objects in an array and iterate through them.  That deep nesting is horrible.

Comment: Wouldn't that code be more readable and have a lot less unnecessary repetition if you put the DateFormat objects in a collection? Lord that's hard on the eyes and a debugging nightmare.

Comment: @ DawoodibnKareem I tried that with trim() on the string and also by replaceAll("\\s","") and then trying to parse ddMMMyyy but no luck

Comment: Yes apologies for the code nesting. I'll tidy it up into an array

Comment: Your code the way it's written tries `dd_MMM_yy`, but just exits if that fails.   It's not trying any of the other formats.

Comment: What is the purpose of `VisitDate.matches(".*[a-z].*"))`? That will not capture any strings with only numbers such as `dd MM yy`

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem the other formats are used for `format()`, not `parse()`.

Comment: True that.  It would help if OP had only posted the relevant code, instead of all that extra stuff.

Comment: You haven’t started using the modern Java date and time classes yet? What is holding you back? For starters, a `LocalDate` matches your need much better than an oldfashioned `Date`.

Comment: Ok @OleV.V. thanks for the heads up. I will investigate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happy to read your expressed interest in the modern date and time classes, here’s just a snippet to get you started:

```
    String visitDate = " 5 April 2017  ";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM uuuu", Locale.UK);
    visitDate = visitDate.trim();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(visitDate, parseFormatter);
    // reformat to the string we like
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd_MM_uu");
    visitDate = date.format(formatter);
```

The result is

```
05_04_17
```

I have spelled `visitDate` with a small v since the Java coding conventions recommend that variable names begin with a small letter.

The `uu` is subtle and probably something you can ignore. It’s a signed year where 0 equals 1 BC, -1 equals 2 BC and so forth. Assuming none of your dates are that old, you can use `u` and `y` interchangeably.

I believe that neither `SimpleDateFormat.format()` nor `LocalDate.format()` will ever return null, so all your null checks are superfluous.

Link for further reading: [Oracle tutorial: Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Comment: Correct Answer. As others noted, the original poster can make a collection (a `List`) of `DateTimeFormatter` objects. Add one formatter for each of the expected formats. Then try each in a `for` loop. Trap for the exception thrown by the `parse` method if the input does not match that particular format. When one formatter succeeds (does not throw an exception), break out of the `for` loop. If none of the formatters work, then you know you received unexpected input.

Comment: In the OP's method, parsing is only being performed by one formatter. The rest of the formatters are being used for output. The logic of the method is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one SimpleDateFormatter being used for parsing:

```
SimpleDateFormat changeDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_yy", Locale.UK);
//Convert the string to a date
Date date = changeDate.parse(VisitDate);
```

It is using the format `dd_MMM_yy`, however you are passing 4 digits for the year.

The rest of your SimpleDateFormatters are being used for formatting to a string, not parsing from a string. Only the first one will be called, since it will be able to produce a string given a valid date, and the following null checks will stop any other formatters from being used.

Comment: I dont think this is correct. From the javadocs "Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number."  so that "dd_MMM_yy" should work fine (and it does strangely for 5 April 2017 when the text is from a doc file but not for a pdf! Maybe this is a text encoding problem?

Comment: OK. It turns out it was an odd non breaking space character that wasn't allowing the date to be parsed. Lesson for me about nbsp's I suppose

Comment: Edited to indicate that the number of year digits is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You have the input string to parse like this: `" 5 April 2017  "`. But you have no pattern match for this input

First please trim the space of input string

Second please change the format of your string or add another pattern to parse this string, because you have month `April` with 5 letter, but you have no pattern with `MMMMM`. Usually the month will be shorten to 3 letter like: April -> Apr, March -> Mar ...

Comment: Any one who vote down this comment, please tell the reason why to help me improve what wrong!

Comment: You don‘t need exactly 5 `M`s for April, just 4 or more for full month name (you are correct that three `M`s are for the three letter abbrevialtion) (I didn’t downvote).